# cannot create a local file using await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

Tags: flutter

when I run the following function

```
_makeFile() async{
  final dataFile = 'data.txt';
  final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final file = File('${directory.path}/$dataFile');

    var isExist = await file.exists();
    if (isExist) {
      print('File exists');
    } else {
      print('file does not exist');
    }

}
```

I get :

flutter: file does not exist

Flutter doctor :

## jfb @ ezer in ~/FTest/file_exist [12:16:41]

$ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Mac OS X 10.15.2 19C57, locale en-FR)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.5 at /usr/local/flutter
    • Framework revision 27321ebbad (4 weeks ago), 2019-12-10 18:15:01 -0800
    • Engine revision 2994f7e1e6
    • Dart version 2.7.0

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/jfb/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.3, Build version 11C29
    • CocoaPods version 1.8.3

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • iPhone 11 Pro Max • 1669648E-FBC3-41D7-9DA0-8E4FF5EBB360 • ios •
      com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-3 (simulator)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.

I just do not understand what's happening, I used this approach in order to store json without problem

Thanks for any pointer ...

JF

Comment: Have you declared `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` & `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission?

Comment: On top of the above comment, have you checked that the directory path you are getting with `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` is the same as the one where you have your `data.txt` file? As a side note, why don't you run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` as instructed to fix the missing licenses?

Answer (score 0):

This line :

```dart
final file = File('${directory.path}/$dataFile');
```

does not create a `File` but only a reference.

To create a `File`, you need to use `writeAsString()` or `writeAsBytes()`.

Retry by adding :

```dart
final dataFile = 'data.txt';
final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
final file = File('${directory.path}/$dataFile');

await file.writeAsString('This is data.txt content'); // <-- This line

print(await file.exists() ? 'Exists' : 'Do not exists');
```